# Fitting a market unit sales S-Curve with R

Tags: r, statistics

I have been tasked with fitting some market sales curves base on macro-economic data using several independent variables; I have 14 years of history.  Sample data would be:

```
UnitSales,GDP,GDPPerCap,CPI,PropInvIndex,DispIncTopDecile,TransCommSecDecile,CivilVehOwn,Urban,AutoFin
" 2,833 ",1198243.4,949,81.62,4984,10643,618,1609,36.22,0
" 7,607 ",1324337.8,1042,81.38,6344,14219,782,1802,37.66,0
" 10,098 ",1453827.558,1135,80.8,7790.9223,18995.9,991.2,2053.17,39.08978381,0
" 18,649 ",1640958.735,1274,81.83,10153.8009,21837.3,1106,2382.93,40.53022975,0
" 14,525 ",1931644.33,1409,85.02,13158.2516,25377.2,1274.2,2693.71,41.76000862,0
" 19,149 ",2256902.591,1731,86.56,15909.2471,28773.1,1590.3,3160,42.98999663,0
" 22,474 ",2712950.885,2069,87.83,19422.9174,31967.3,1801,3697.3531,44.34301016,0
" 32,573 ",3494055.942,2651,92.02,25288.8373,36784.5,2467.7,4358.355,45.8892446,0.1
" 42,186 ",4521827.271,3414,97.45,31203.1942,43613.8,2632.9,5099.6094,46.98950317,0.12
" 52,765 ",4990233.519,3749,96.76,36241.808,46826.1,3181.9,6280.6086,48.34170101,0.14
" 140,855 ",5930502.27,4433,100,48259.403,51431.6,3630.6,7801.8259,49.94966105,0.16
" 88,873 ",7321891.955,5447,105.45,61796.8858,58841.9,3963,9356.3163,51.27027127,0.18
" 161,082 ",8229490.03,6093,108.22,71803.7869,63824.2,4304.1,10933.0912,52.57008656,0.22
" 149,197 ",9240270.452,6807,111.07,86013.3826,68874.37491,4748.669569,12670.1435,53.73,0.26
```

Of the macroeconomic variables I have, I can use just a subset if degrees of freedom become an issue. Since the data are products that follow a lifecycle and have market saturation effects the curves should be S-curves or sigmoidal.  In my attempts in R I have only been able to fit exponential (J-curve) curves; I have tried tslm (from fpp package) to fit the model.

My current R code is

```
# rm(list=ls())
ds <- read.csv(file='c:/RCode/Output/PremM.csv', header=T, sep=',')
tsdata <-ts(ds, s=2000)
results<- tslm(UnitSales~GDP+GPDPerCap+CPI+trend, data=tsdata)

write.csv(coef(results), file = "c:/Rcode/Output/CoefPremM.csv")

sink('C:/RCode/Output/PremMSummary2.txt',append=F,type="output")
summary(results)
sink(NULL)
```

The tslm package isn't working.  I'm at the very edge of my competence and have only learned R for this project, so am a newbie.  If someone could point me to an appropriate R package and sample code I would be eternally grateful.  The examples I've seen have all been with logistic curves for binary data which don't seem appropriate to my task.

Your help is appreciated at year's end.

Comment: Do not post `rm` statements. (I have commented it out.)  Also there are read statements for multiple files in the sample code but only one data file shown. Please clean this up and make everything consistent.  Also, "is not working" is not a useful description.  Exactly what the question is here is not clear.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback; I have edited my question to remove the portions that are extraneous.  My question is I need to fit an S-curve, but the tslm is producing a J-curve.  What package in R is best to fit an S-curve for market saturation of a product.

Comment: See `?nls` and `?SSlogis` from base R?

Comment: At the moment the outcome variable is probably being read as a factor when it should be a count. As a start try `ds$UnitSales=as.numeric(gsub("[,]", "", as.character(ds$UnitSales)`